# Что должен содержать файл /etc/timezone и как его содержимое соотносится с /etc/localtime?

Tags: linux

Дистрибутив Ubuntu 18.04, пишу утилиту, которая меняет timezone. Как менять /etc/localtime, я разобрался, а вот по /etc/timezone не могу найти информацию, например, что он должен содержать, когда /etc/localtime ссылается на /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/GMT?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452559

Answer (score 1):

timezone содержит текстовое название временной зоны. Ни на что не влияет, разве что для совместимости с программами не умеющими обрабатывать localtime.

Если  /etc/localtime ссылается на /usr/share/zoneinfo/**Etc/GMT** должен содержать

```
Etc/GMT
```

Comment: Спасибо, возможно ли добавить ссылку на информацию, где это описано?

Comment: например по ссылке что дает  andreymal есть обсуждение в коментариях. но по поводу явы там много - для openjdk-11 не актуально уже